# Android (Xamarin) ListView position issue

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, adapter

I'm working on a ListView that populates data beyond the screen (requires scrolling) and faced the issue of data duplication. Through some research, I've implemented a ViewHolder with fixed the issue of repeating data. However, some elements in the ListView do not work with data - but rather position instead - and those as a result still get messed up everytime I scroll through the view and it recycles itself. Here is the ListView adapter and ViewHolder code:

```
public class ListAdapter : BaseAdapter
   {
       private readonly Activity activity;

       public ListAdapter(Activity a)
       {
           activity = a;
       }

       public override int Count
       {
           get { return nameTexts.Length; }
       }

       public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
       {
           return null;
       }

       public override long GetItemId(int position)
       {
           return 0;
       }

       public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
       {
           ViewHolder holder;
           View view = convertView;

           if (view == null)
           {
               holder = new ViewHolder();

               view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Hospital_List_Item, parent, false);
               holder.hospitalName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.selectHospital_HospitalText);

               view.Click += delegate
               {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(activity, typeof(Request_Appointment));
                   intent.PutExtra("hospitalName", nameTexts[position]);
                   activity.StartActivity(intent);
               };

               //  Set alternatiing background of row
               if (position % 2 == 1)
               {
                   view.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color._8_white);
               }

               view.Tag = holder;
           }
           else
           {
               holder = view.Tag as ViewHolder;
           }            

           //  Set height of row
           view.LayoutParameters.Height = Select_Hospital.LIST_HEIGHT / 6;

           //  Row contents
           holder.hospitalName.Text = nameTexts[position];
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(position);



           return view;
       }

       private readonly string[] nameTexts =
       {
           "Hospital 1",
           "Hospital 2",
           "Hospital 3",
           "Hospital 4",
           "Hospital 5",
           "Hospital 6",
           "Hospital 7",
           "Hospital 8",
           "Hospital 9",
           "Hospital 10",
           "Hospital 11",
           "Hospital 12",
           "Hospital 13",
           "Hospital 14",
           "Hospital 15",
           "Hospital 16",
           "Hospital 17",
           "Hospital 18",
           "Hospital 19",
           "Hospital 20",
           "Hospital 21",
           "Hospital 22",
           "Hospital 23",
           "Hospital 24",
           "Hospital 25"
       };
   }

   //  ViewHolder
   class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
   {
       public TextView hospitalName { get; set; }
       public ToggleButton hospitalFavourites { get; set; }
   }
```

Hospital_List_Item axml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectHospital_HospitalText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/dark_blue" />
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/selectHospital_FavouritesToggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Initial screen:

[image: Initial]

After scrolling:

[image: After scroll]

Note: Clicking on any row item displays the position of the the row clicked, which returns a wrong value after scrolling.

The elements that are not working as intended are the alternating backgrounds as well as the click event. I tried shifting those outside of the if (view == null) block but that makes it even worse. Any help is much appreciated!

**-EDIT-**

Updated code:

```
public class ListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private readonly Activity activity;

    public ListAdapter(Activity a)
    {
        activity = a;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return nameTexts.Length; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;
        int type;

        if (view == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Hospital_List_Item, parent, false);
            holder.hospitalName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.selectHospital_HospitalText);
            holder.hospitalFavourites = view.FindViewById<ToggleButton>(Resource.Id.selectHospital_FavouritesToggle);
            holder.position = position;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(holder.position);

            view.Click += delegate
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(activity, typeof(Request_Appointment));
                intent.PutExtra("hospitalName", holder.hospitalName.Text);
                activity.StartActivity(intent);
            };

            view.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = view.Tag as ViewHolder;
        }            

        //  Set height of row
        view.LayoutParameters.Height = Select_Hospital.LIST_HEIGHT / 6;

        //  Set alternating background of row
        type = GetItemViewType(holder.position);

        if (type == 0)
        {
            view.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color._8_white);
        }

        //  Row contents
        holder.hospitalName.Text = nameTexts[position];

        holder.hospitalFavourites.Text = position.ToString();
        holder.hospitalFavourites.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.hospitalFavourites.Click += delegate
            {
                holder.hospitalFavourites.Text = position.ToString();
            };

        return view;
    }

    //  Number of different rows
    public override int ViewTypeCount
    {
        get
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    //  To alternate rows
    public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return position % 2 == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    }        

    private readonly string[] nameTexts =
    {
        "Hospital 1",
        "Hospital 2",
        "Hospital 3",
        "Hospital 4",
        "Hospital 5",
        "Hospital 6",
        "Hospital 7",
        "Hospital 8",
        "Hospital 9",
        "Hospital 10",
        "Hospital 11",
        "Hospital 12",
        "Hospital 13",
        "Hospital 14",
        "Hospital 15",
        "Hospital 16",
        "Hospital 17",
        "Hospital 18",
        "Hospital 19",
        "Hospital 20",
        "Hospital 21",
        "Hospital 22",
        "Hospital 23",
        "Hospital 24",
        "Hospital 25"
    };
}

class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView hospitalName { get; set; }
    public ToggleButton hospitalFavourites { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
}
```

**-EDIT 2- (OnClick lambda)**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private readonly Activity activity;
    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Activity a)
    {
        activity = a;
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get
        {
            return nameTexts.Length;
        }
    }

    private void OnClick (int position)
    {
        ItemClick?.Invoke(this, position);
    }

    private void OnItemClick(object sender, int position)
    {
        int buttonNum = position + 1;
        Toast.MakeText(activity, "This is button number " + buttonNum, ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return position % 2 == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        ViewHolder vh = holder as ViewHolder;

        //  Set height of row
        vh.ItemView.LayoutParameters.Height = Select_Hospital.LIST_HEIGHT / 6;

        //  Set alternating background of row
        int type = GetItemViewType(position);

        if (type == 0)
        {
            vh.ItemView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color._8_white);
        }

        vh.hospitalName.Text = nameTexts[position];
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.sublayout_Hospital_List_Item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view, OnClick);

        holder.ItemView.Click += delegate
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, typeof(Request_Appointment));
            intent.PutExtra("hospitalName", holder.hospitalName.Text);
            activity.StartActivity(intent);
        };

        ItemClick += OnItemClick;

        return holder;
    }

    private readonly string[] nameTexts =
    {
        "Hospital 1",
        "Hospital 2",
        "Hospital 3",
        "Hospital 4",
        "Hospital 5",
        "Hospital 6",
        "Hospital 7",
        "Hospital 8",
        "Hospital 9",
        "Hospital 10",
        "Hospital 11",
        "Hospital 12",
        "Hospital 13",
        "Hospital 14",
        "Hospital 15",
        "Hospital 16",
        "Hospital 17",
        "Hospital 18",
        "Hospital 19",
        "Hospital 20",
        "Hospital 21",
        "Hospital 22",
        "Hospital 23",
        "Hospital 24",
        "Hospital 25"
    };
}

class ViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView hospitalName { get; set; }
    public ToggleButton hospitalFavourites { get; set; }

    public ViewHolder (View view, Action<int> listener) : base(view)
    {
        hospitalName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.selectHospital_HospitalText);
        hospitalFavourites = view.FindViewById<ToggleButton>(Resource.Id.selectHospital_FavouritesToggle);

        hospitalFavourites.Click += (sender, e) => listener(AdapterPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have different layouts for different listView items

Comment: @AyushKhare Sorry could you elaborate on that?

Comment: You have rows with different colors, you should implement getItemViewType() with count as 2. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html)

Comment: @AyushKhare Thank you! That solved the issue with the background. I'm still having problems with the click method though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it with the following code:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter_SelectHospital : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private readonly Context context;
    private List<Hospital> list;
    public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter_SelectHospital(Context c, List<Hospital> l)
    {
        context = c;
        list = l;
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get
        {
            return list.Count;
        }
    }

    private void OnClick(int position)
    {
        ItemClick?.Invoke(this, position);
    }

    private void OnItemClick(object sender, int position)
    {
        if (list[position].favourited == false)
        {
            list[position].favourited = true;
        }
        else
        {
            list[position].favourited = false;
        }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return position % 2 == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        SelectHospital_ViewHolder vh = holder as SelectHospital_ViewHolder;

        //  Set height of row
        vh.ItemView.LayoutParameters.Height = Select_Hospital.LIST_HEIGHT / 6;

        //  Set alternating background of row
        int type = GetItemViewType(position);

        if (type == 0)
        {
            vh.ItemView.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color._8_white);
        }

        vh.hospitalName.Text = list[position].name;
        vh.hospitalFavourites.Checked = list[position].favourited;
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.sublayout_Hospital_List_Item, parent, false);
        SelectHospital_ViewHolder holder = new SelectHospital_ViewHolder(view, OnClick);

        holder.ItemView.Click += delegate
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Request_Appointment));
            intent.PutExtra("hospitalName", holder.hospitalName.Text);
            context.StartActivity(intent);
        };

        ItemClick -= OnItemClick;
        ItemClick += OnItemClick;

        return holder;
    }
}

class SelectHospital_ViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView hospitalName { get; set; }
    public ToggleButton hospitalFavourites { get; set; }

    public SelectHospital_ViewHolder(View view, Action<int> listener) : base(view)
    {
        hospitalName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.selectHospital_HospitalText);
        hospitalFavourites = view.FindViewById<ToggleButton>(Resource.Id.selectHospital_FavouritesToggle);

        hospitalFavourites.Click += (sender, e) => listener(AdapterPosition);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. hospitalFavourites ToggleButton is not assign in GetView method
2. view.Click delegate should be retrieving tag from the view instead of accessing nameTexts[position]. You can add position as a property inside ViewHolder, so you can access it when the list item clicked.
3. Code for alternating background color should be outside of the if (view == null) block.

== EDITED ==

Use the following code to modify what you want to do.

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace ListAdapterSample.Droid
{
public class ListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private readonly Activity activity;

    public ListAdapter(Activity a)
    {
        activity = a;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return nameTexts.Length; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;
        int type;

        if (view == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.hospital_list_item, parent, false);
            holder.hospitalName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.selectHospital_HospitalText);
            holder.hospitalFavourites = view.FindViewById<ToggleButton>(Resource.Id.selectHospital_FavouritesToggle);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(holder.position);

            view.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var senderView = sender as View;
                if (senderView != null)
                {
                    var senderHolder = senderView.Tag as ViewHolder;
                    if (senderHolder != null)
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(activity, senderHolder.position.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    }
                }
            };

            holder.hospitalFavourites.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var senderView = sender as View;
                if (senderView != null)
                {
                    var rowHolder = ((View)senderView.Parent).Tag as ViewHolder;
                    rowHolder.hospitalFavourites.Text = rowHolder.position.ToString();
                };
            };

            view.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = view.Tag as ViewHolder;
        }

        //  Set height of row
        view.LayoutParameters.Height = 200;

        //  Set alternating background of row
        type = GetItemViewType(position);

        if (type == 0)
        {
            //view.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color._8_white);
            view.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.AliceBlue);
        }

        //  Row contents
        holder.position = position;
        holder.hospitalName.Text = nameTexts[position];

        holder.hospitalFavourites.Text = position.ToString();
        holder.hospitalFavourites.SetOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

        return view;
    }

    //  Number of different rows
    public override int ViewTypeCount
    {
        get
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    //  To alternate rows
    public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return position % 2 == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    }

    private readonly string[] nameTexts =
    {
    "Hospital 1",
    "Hospital 2",
    "Hospital 3",
    "Hospital 4",
    "Hospital 5",
    "Hospital 6",
    "Hospital 7",
    "Hospital 8",
    "Hospital 9",
    "Hospital 10",
    "Hospital 11",
    "Hospital 12",
    "Hospital 13",
    "Hospital 14",
    "Hospital 15",
    "Hospital 16",
    "Hospital 17",
    "Hospital 18",
    "Hospital 19",
    "Hospital 20",
    "Hospital 21",
    "Hospital 22",
    "Hospital 23",
    "Hospital 24",
    "Hospital 25"
};
}

class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TextView hospitalName { get; set; }
    public ToggleButton hospitalFavourites { get; set; }
    public int position { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: AyushKhare has solved the problem with the background. I have attempted adding position as a property inside ViewHolder, but that still returned the wrong positions. As for the ToggleButton, I'm not working on that at the moment, so I haven't implemented it yet. It doesn't affect the code.

Comment: @lowteetak I have now implemented the togglebutton, however it also seems to be having duplication problems. For example, when button 1 is toggled, button 7 and button 15 will also be toggled. I have added an edit for the updated code in the original post. Could you help me on this issue?

Comment: You are calling holder.hospitalFavourites.Click += delegate for multiple times. Imagine when you scroll down and the view is recycled, you will be adding another delegate into the favourite button click. THe event binding should be inside the block if (view == null). Also, you will need to recheck on the logic of the favourite button click.

Comment: As of now, clicking on the button will just set its text to the position. After shifting the click event into the if block, not only does the original problem still exist, each click returns a different position after scrolling as well.

Comment: Updated with sample code. You will need to modify what is happening in the click delegate to do what you want.

Comment: Regrettably, I had already converted the listview into a recycleview after reading about the advantages recycleview has over listview, but the problem still remains. Now that I'm using a recycleview with OnCreateViewHolder and OnBindViewHolder methods, how should I implement your code?

Comment: For favourite button, bind the click event inside OnCreateViewHolder to a lambda. Then get the position via ViewHolder.AdapterPosition in the lambda.
For click event, refer to xamarin guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/#Handling_Item-Click_Events

Comment: I have implemented that and made another edit in my post to show the updated code. The problem still remains, and the toast is called multiple times per click.

Comment: The multiple toast messages were easily fixed, but the toggle button issue still remains. Toggling one button automatically toggles another one further down the recyclerview.

Comment: Can put the code online (e.g. github) or paste the latest here. So, I can check it out?

Comment: As @Setar had mentioned, I just added

    ItemClick -= OnItemClick

before

    ItemClick += OnItemClick

. The rest of the code is the same as edit 2

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be your `getItem()` look like this:

```
    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position){
        return nameTexts[position];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be the Delegate in the adapter, that sometimes can be the source of many problems.try using a method delegate instead of a anonymus delegate. and setting the onclick event to null before setting it correctly.

this is becouse the objects are being recycled and the click method can be called twice so you don't need the if(view == null).

I hope you have understood me, im not able to provide a sample proved code but it should look like :

```
.
.
.
view.Click -= customOnClickMethod;
view.Click += customOnClickMethod;
.
.
.
void customOnClickMethod(object sender, EventArgs e){
    //implement onclick function

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried this, but the issue still remains. Checking the one toggle button would still automatically toggle another one further below te recyclerview.